# assert that all fields in 2 objects are the same c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am doing unit testing, and basically want to check that the data that 2 objects hold is the same

```
Assert.AreEqual(object1, object2);   
Assert.IsTrue(object1.Equals(object2)); //this of course doesn't work
```

I am searching for the C# equivalent of [assertJ](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#isEqualToComparingFieldByField(java.lang.Object))

```
Assert.That(object1).isEqualToComparingFieldByField(object2)
```

Comment: Are both objects of the same type? If yes, you should create a comparer class that implements `IEqualityComparer<YourType>` and call it e.g. `Assert.Equal(MyComparer.Default.Equals(object1, object2))`

Comment: What is a field for you? Is a property also a field, does it has to be public or is protected or even private ok?

Comment: @raga70 [FluentAssertion](https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/) does support this kind of object graph comparisons, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use records (c# 9 +) or you have to override the Equals method (if you have access and you can change the objects that you're working with).
Records example:

```
var point = new Point(3, 4);
var point2 = new Point(3, 4);

var test = point.Equals(point2); //this is true

public record Point(int X, int Y);
```

with classes:

```
public class Point
{
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }


    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
         return false;

        return obj is Point point && (point.X == X && point.Y == Y);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(X, Y);
    }
}
```

if you are not allowed to touch the implementation, then you could use serialization and compare the strings:

```
var obj1Str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object1);
var obj2Str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object2);
Assert.Equal(obj1Str, obj2Str);
```

using *Newtonsoft.Json* nuget

Comment: You could mention that structs also has a default equals implementation of "value equality".

Comment: You don't *have* to override `Equals`, and honestly, I wouldn't even suggest it. By overriding `Equals` you're changing the way the object acts *globally*, but sometime in the future OP, or another dev on the project, will (most likely) want to check reference equality somewhere, at that point in time they'll have to remember that `Point` doesn't behave like a normal object and have to manually call `object.ReferenceEquals(point1, point2)`

Comment: @MindSwipe, if he's using DDD for example, ValueObjects should behave exactly like this. again, it's one option, it can't fit all the scenarios, but maybe it will help someone, but you're right, you do need to know that whatever you're doing at the class level it will be reflected in the object behavior.

Answer (score 1):

C# classes are reference equality, which means that variables are the same using the standard `Equals` and `==` if they point to the same object, you could override that behaivour, but it may break something now or in the future.

Or, you could switch to using a construct that's value equality by default, which `struct`s as well as `record class`es are. If you can't (or don't want to) do that you can implement a value equals "helper" method yourself. I would **not** recommend overriding the `Equals` method or the `==` operator, as that can (and most likely will) lead to errors in the future instead I recommend you write your own `ValueEquals` method or extension method, something along the lines of

```cs
class Foo
{
    public int Count {get; set;}

    public string Message {get; set;}
}

public static bool ValueEquals(this Foo self, Foo other)
{
    return self.Count == other.Count && self.Message == other.Message;
}

public void MyTest()
{
    // Arrange and Act
    ...

    // Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(myFoo1.ValueEquals(myFoo2));
}
```

Depending on whether or not you can/ want to add a `ValueEquals` to your `Foo` class you can decide on doing it with an extension method or a normal method.

You could also implement a `IEqualityComparer<T>` like

```cs
public class FooValueEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{
    public bool Equals(Foo foo1, Foo foo2)
    {
        return foo1.Count == foo2.Count &&
               foo1.Message == foo2.Message;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Foo foo)
    {
        return foo.GetHashCode();
    }
}

// Use it
public void MyTest()
{
    // Arrange and Act
    ...

    // Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(new FooEqualityComparer().Equals(myFoo1, myFoo2));
}
```

---

*Or*, you could write a generic `ValueEquals` that works for all^* classes using Reflection:

```cs
public static class ValueEqualityComparer
{
    public static bool ValueEquals<T>(this T self, T other) where T : class
    {
        var type = self.GetType();
        if (type == typeof(string))
            return self.Equals(other);

        var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var selfValue = property.GetValue(self);
            var otherValue = property.GetValue(other);

            // String is special, it's not primitive but is value equality like primitives
            if (property.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                if (!selfValue.Equals(otherValue))
                    return false;
            }
            // If the property is a List value equals each member
            // Maybe find another type that allows indexing and is less restrictive
            else if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
            {
                var selfList = ((IEnumerable)property.GetValue(self)).Cast<object>();
                var otherList = ((IEnumerable)property.GetValue(other)).Cast<object>();

                try
                {
                    // Using EquiZip from MoreLinq: https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/EquiZip.cs
                    foreach (var element in selfList.EquiZip(otherList, (selfItem, otherItem) => new { selfItem, otherItem }))
                    {
                        if (!ValueEquals(element.selfItem, element.otherItem))
                            return false;
                    }
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    // MoreLINQ throws a InvalidOperationException if our two enumerables aren't the same length
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!ValueEquals(selfValue, otherValue))
                    return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

This implementation is by no means perfect, and should honestly only be used for UnitTests and also should be thoroughly tested itself. You can see my tests as a dotnetfiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a2cfFs)

Or you could do it "dirty" and serialize the objects to a string and compare those values.